# Evitar de removerem o TestProvider do Mock Location

Tags: android, gps, mock

Estou tentando mockar localização para utilização em uma outra aplicação, mas essa aplicação está removendo meu TestProvider, fazendo com que não seja possível mockar a localização.

Como posso evitar esse outro app de remover meu **TestProvider**?

O código que a outra aplicação está executando para evitar o mock é:

```
private void BuscarLocalizacaoAtual(String provider, LocationListener locationListener) {
    try {
        this.locationManager.removeTestProvider(provider);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time, 0.0f, locationListener);
}
```

*Gostaria inicialmente de conseguir driblar esse problema através de um apk. Sei que poderia fazer isso editando o sistema operacional.

bounty de 100 para quem me ajudar a driblar esse negócio.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta traduzida do SOen:

Parece que a única maneira de fazer é usar um provedor de localização simulada.

Você precisa habilitar locais fictícios no painel de desenvolvimento e em suas configurações adicionar ao seu manifesto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Agora você pode ir no seu código e criar seu próprio provedor de localização falsa e definir a localização do provedor.

[Aqui um local bacana para pegar mais alguns detalhes!](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/)

Comment: No exemplo que você informou ele usa o lm.addTestProvider, o código do app remove o test provider, anulando o mock location.